# Get FileUploads and insert to database dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

How to get entire file upload[all attributes] when post-back is triggered?

I'm create a table with `Label`, `textBox` and `FileUpload` [ASP.net component but not HTML] to get sub_category name and upload sub_category logo.

Requirements:

1. All the `FileUpload` should be created dynamically with IDs accordingly.

Tried approaches:

1. Add fileuploads [HTML - `<input type="file"/>`] by running `javascript` dynamically and `FindControl` at code behind; `runat="server"` is not able to be added to the element.
2. Add `FileUpload` [ASP.net] by `javascript`; it was nothing display at all.
3. `HttpPostedFile subcat_file = Request.Files["FU_cat_logo_" + i];`

What would be the solution to handle this scenario?

Sample image:

[image: Sample]

Comment: it's really unclear what you are asking. post some related code

Comment: I have put more info about my case. Please kindly have a look, thank you.

Comment: I think best approach is using a ViewState. It is best solution for dynamic pages, as far I know